# Set images' width to 80% of screen width (multiple divs)

Tags: html, css

Please see:
https://codepen.io/alanvkarlik/pen/vdWyrd

I'm lost atm. My website has images that show up when you hover over the bold text links.

Right now they are showing up with original size, sometimes stretching beyond the screen.

I'd like them all to have the same width - say 80% of the screen width. Where and how do I edit that?

The main block with those links is centered with following divs:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="table-container">
<div id="content">
```

and their css:

```
#wrapper {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.table-container {
height:100%;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 55%;
display:table;
text-align: center;
}

#content {
vertical-align:middle;
height:100%;
display:table-cell;
max-width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 3vw;
line-height: 4vw;
font-family: 'Vesper Libre', serif;
text-align: justify;
color: #fff;
}
```

Basically I used this set up to make sure the block of links is always in the centre of the screen (both width and height wise).

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Please make sure you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you without going to CodePen where your code might change in the future.

Comment: there are no img tags in the code you posted here...

Comment: @chriskirknielsen just updated the code for this example only - hope now it follows the guidelines

Comment: @Johannes yes I noticed that after chriskirknielsen posted his answer - thank you for pointing it out - will make sure to remember that in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using the `vw` unit, so just use that for your image:

```
.hover_link img {
  width: 80vw;
  height: auto;
}
```

I also suggest you remove `display: none;` from `.hover_img span` as this will nullify your `opacity` transition (you can add `pointer-events: none;` to cancel any mouse event on the `span` and its contents).